# How to write a nodejs code, to handle android and nodejs client?

Tags: android, node.js, cross-platform

I have a server and client architecture, both are written in node js. Now we introduced a android client. How to modify the server code to handle both nodejs and android client?. It will be great, if you point out any example. I have been advised to use interface?. Is it an effective methodology?.

Comment: How's your server - client communicates? through APIs right?

Comment: @GeorgePJ Client - server communication is like, Client hits the server endpoint, client may be nodejs or Android. Based on the client, server has to process the request. So single API endpoint in the server, has to handle both nodejs and Android.

Comment: So you are using REST Webservice APIs so that you can consume it in android with the help of some libraries such as Retrofit. Usually, the server treats its clients in the same manner regardless of client-side technology.

Comment: @GeorgePJ . No. My question is how to handle two different codebase in server, not how to detect the requesting client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design Factory pattern really helps me to resolve my issue. I got a reference for java [ref](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm)